# Understanding of CASE with ORDER BY in SQL

Tags: sql, case-when

I am trying to revise my SQL concepts, and while doing so, I faced a curious case which I was not  able to understand. Below is my schema and data:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer 
(
    name varchar(255),
    city varchar(255),
    country varchar(255),
    id int
);

INSERT INTO customer VALUES ("ram923", null, "aIndia3",1);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ("ram92", null, "dIndia3",1);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ("ram83", null, "dIndia4",1);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ("ram94", null, "dIndia4",1);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ("ram", "city1", "bIndia1",1);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ("ram1", "city2", "aIndia1",1);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ("ram2", "city3", "aIndia1",1);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ("ram3", "city4", "bIndia2",1);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ("ram4", "city5", "bIndia2",1);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ("ram8", null, "bIndia2",1);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ("ram9", null, "bIndia2",1);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ("ram5", "city6", "cIndia3",1);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ("ram6", "city7", "dIndia4",1);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ("ram67", "city71", "dIndia3",1);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ("ram622", null, "eIndia3",1);
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ("ram81", null, "cIndia3",1);
```

Then I execute this select query which would use `CASE` statement with `ORDER BY` to order the customers by City. However, if City is NULL, then order by Country:

```
SELECT 
    name, City, Country
FROM
    Customer
ORDER BY
    (CASE
        WHEN City IS NULL THEN Country
        ELSE City
     END);
```

The output I get is not quite the way I thought it would be:

```
name    City    Country
------------------------
ram923  (null)  aIndia3
ram8    (null)  bIndia2
ram9    (null)  bIndia2
ram81   (null)  cIndia3
ram     city1   bIndia1
ram1    city2   aIndia1
ram2    city3   aIndia1
ram3    city4   bIndia2
ram4    city5   bIndia2
ram5    city6   cIndia3
ram6    city7   dIndia4
ram67   city71  dIndia3
ram92   (null)  dIndia3
ram83   (null)  dIndia4
ram94   (null)  dIndia4
ram622  (null)  eIndia3
```

Can anyone explain how the `CASE` with `ORDER BY` is working here? Why it would not put all `null` cities together and then do `ORDER BY` country?

Comment: Copy the case to the SELECT list, and you'll see.

Comment: didn't get. Can you type in query which you want me to try?

Comment: Simply write the same case expression one more time, `SELECT name, City, Country, case ... from ...`.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is hard to understand?  You can see the sorting key by replacing the expression, although I would simplify it as:

```
select c.*, coalesce(city, country)
from customers c
order by coalesce(city, country);
```

In your sample data, all the `country` values are before the `city` values alphabetically.

Comment: Oh yes! The coalesce thing helped me understand this! Basically, it took country column to sort it if city was null. I verified this by changing city value to start with something more advanced alphabetically which cleared the doubt. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone explain how the CASE with ORDER BY is working here?

Simply add the expression used in ORDER BY, to output list:

> ```
> SELECT name, City, Country
> , CASE WHEN City IS NULL 
>        THEN Country
>        ELSE City END expression_from_order_by
> FROM customer
> ORDER BY
> (CASE
>     WHEN City IS NULL THEN Country
>     ELSE City
> END);
> ```

| name | City | Country | expression_from_order_by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ram923 | *null* | aIndia3 | aIndia3 |
| ram8 | *null* | bIndia2 | bIndia2 |
| ram9 | *null* | bIndia2 | bIndia2 |
| ram81 | *null* | cIndia3 | cIndia3 |
| ram | city1 | bIndia1 | city1 |
| ram1 | city2 | aIndia1 | city2 |
| ram2 | city3 | aIndia1 | city3 |
| ram3 | city4 | bIndia2 | city4 |
| ram4 | city5 | bIndia2 | city5 |
| ram5 | city6 | cIndia3 | city6 |
| ram6 | city7 | dIndia4 | city7 |
| ram67 | city71 | dIndia3 | city71 |
| ram92 | *null* | dIndia3 | dIndia3 |
| ram83 | *null* | dIndia4 | dIndia4 |
| ram94 | *null* | dIndia4 | dIndia4 |
| ram622 | *null* | eIndia3 | eIndia3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6968383cf1075a05945517c1093adbd8)*

Now it is absolutely clear how does it works.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way understand how a case expression affects your `order by` clause is to output the same case expression as part of the `select` clause

```
SELECT
      name , City , Country
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN City IS NULL
                THEN Country
            ELSE City
            END
        ) AS sort_by_case
FROM Customer
ORDER BY 
        CASE 
            WHEN City IS NULL
                THEN Country
            ELSE City
            END
;
```

or:

```
SELECT
      name , City , Country
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN City IS NULL
                THEN Country
            ELSE City
            END
        ) AS sort_by_case
FROM Customer
ORDER BY 
      sort_by_case
;
```